# Rename [research] to [researching]

Tags: feature-request, tags

[research](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) is frequently used for almost all sorts of questions only marginally related to research, such as publishing a research paper.

In hope to reduce this misuse, I suggest to rename it to [researching](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/researching), which has the advantage of excluding the product of research, but still includes performing research, which the tag is about.
This should happen **without** synonymising [research](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research), because the change would be pointless otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with [researching](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/researching) is that it uses a word form that is rarely used in standard American English. (That is, not many people would say "I am researching. . . ." Instead, they'd likely say: "My research does X. . . " or something similar.

I agree with the need for a split tag, but perhaps [research-process](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-process) would convey what you're after better?

Comment: Sounds good by me. Note though, that I am not proposing to **split** the tag, but to rename it. There is no need for a tag *research* in the world I am proposing.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the current body of questions tagged [research](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research), it does seem like the tag needs to be split, not just renamed. Most of the questions currently tagged [research](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) are *not* about the research process. Most of them already have tags that classify them well, so I suggest creating synonyms starting with "research-", for all the people who believe they need to tag their questions with "research" and starts typing it into the tag input field.

I suggest (based on the types of existing questions currently tagged [research](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research)):

- [research-process](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-process) - for questions about the process of doing research.
- [research-experience](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-experience) - for questions about research experience on a CV, impact of research experience on graduate admissions, etc.
- [research-workplace](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-workplace) - for Workplace.SE-like questions about working in an academic environment, what is the work of a researcher like, etc. Should be made as a synonym of [workplace](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workplace).
- [research-topic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-topic) - (already exists) for questions about choosing a research topic, etc.
- [research-misconduct](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-misconduct) - (already exists) for questions about fraud and other misconduct
- [research-publication](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-publication) - should be created as a synonym of [publications](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publications).
- [research-supervision](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-supervision) - as a synonym of [supervision](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supervision).

I may be missing some, that will come up as we attempt to re-tag all the mis-tagged questions in [research](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research).

Comment: I proposed something like this a while back: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/863/929. Your list is better and the problem is bigger now.

Comment: @StrongBad Thanks for pointing that out, I had forgotten about that. I think most of the objection to your suggestion was because you seemed to indicate that [tag:research-undergraduate] wasn't needed as a separate tag. (At least, I downvoted it for that reason.)