# Reorganising research-related tags a bit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-cleanup-proposal

#### Proposal

I would like to implement the following tag structure as already suggested and reasoned in [this answer](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2063/7734). An arrow means that the respective tags are merged and synonymised, with the right tag being the master.

- [research](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) → [research-process](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-process)
- [research-publication](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-publication), [research-paper](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-paper) → [publications](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publications)
- [research-workplace](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-workplace) → [workplace](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workplace)
- [research-supervision](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-supervision) → [supervision](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supervision)
- [research-topic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-topic)
- [research-misconduct](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-misconduct)
- [research-statement](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-statement)
- [research-undergraduate](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-undergraduate)

This is not a big change. There will be a few synonyms that link to existing tags and *research* will be renamed. Questions that are mistagged with [research](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) will continue to be mistagged. There will be no merges of existing tags or burninations.

Note that in contrast to what I proposed in the linked question, I would not remove [research](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) in hope that the synonymisation would suffice to stop people from choosing this tag (in the tag-selection process, they would have to actively click on [research-process](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-process)).

#### This question

I am mainly bringing this up again, because the old post was, well, old and did not receive much feedback. If you have any objections or better suggestions, please voice them here and now. Otherwise, I will implement this in a week or so.

Comment: Currently, there is no question tagged [research-workplace], 51 questions tagger with [workplace] (at least one of them is about library workplace). I think I'll agree with [workplace]. But, I am still concerned with new users abusing it. (If I remember it correctly, there were at one user(or more) coming to our site using that tag for an industry workplace question). We might want to remind those users in the tag description. I am going to delete my answer below.

Comment: @scaaahu: *We might want to remind those users in the tag description.* – Well, feel free to suggest an edit.