# Rename review-articles tag to literature-review-articles

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I subscribe to the [review-articles](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-articles) tag, whose description is this:

> "Survey" or "review" articles are academic publications that organize
>   and summarize the current state of research on a given topic in a
>   novel way that integrates and adds understanding to work in the field.
>   For questions related to the peer-review process, use the
>   'peer-review' tag instead.

Despite this explanation (which many people, especially new posters, apparently never get around to reading), maybe as many as 50% of the questions with that tag actually pertain to peer reviewing and have nothing to do with literature review articles.

Hence, I propose to rename the tag [literature-review-articles](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature-review-articles), which I think should be more explicit in communicating the correct intention of the tag. In that case, I also propose deleting the [review-articles](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-articles) tag; that is, **not** leaving it as a synonym, since that would perpetuate the confusion.

If this makes sense, then could someone with the right permissions please make the change?

Comment: To support my point, here's another one that came in after I posted this question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/111540/revisions

Comment: In the meantime, I've created: the tag and I've added it to several existing articles. I hope it will soon be eligible to be proposed as a synonym: https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/lit-review-articles/info

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to have abbreviations in tag names. `literature-review-articles` would be better.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Revised accordingly

Comment: And here's another example: https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/111996/revisions

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to comment regarding logistics: the best way to rename a tag is

- post on meta to find out if the community supports or is opposed to the tag renaming.
- if there is community support, moderators will "merge" the tag which effectively renames it.

It's generally not recommended to just start adding or replacing the tag manually, especially for a tag with many questions. (1) This can be confusing for people who are new ("what is the difference between these tags, which should I use for my question on a survey paper?") or who are used to the old tag schema. (2) It also bumps a bunch of questions to the top of the home page, which some people don't like.

(For reason #1, I have renamed the [lit-review-articles](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lit-review-articles) back to [review-articles](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-articles) for now. Once there is agreement on a new name for the tag, and the need for it, a moderator can rename [review-articles](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-articles) again.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and correction.

Answer (score 0):

Less than two weeks ago, I implemented [a similar renaming](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4145/7734): Before, there was only [research](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research); now, there is a synonym [research](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) → [research-process](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-process). While this tag was blatantly misapplied on a daily basis before (I subscribed to the tag just to remove it), it has not happened since then. This shows two things:

- Renaming the tag is indeed effective.
- Only the master tag matters – very likely because this is what is shown when typing *research* into the tag field when [asking a new question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) (best try for yourself).

I also second [Federico Poloni’s comment](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4221/rename-review-articles-tag-to-lit-review-articles#comment12871_4221) that abbreviations should be avoided in tags.

I thus suggest to have the following tag structure:

- [review-articles](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-articles) → [literature-review-articles](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature-review-articles)
- [review-papers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-papers) → [literature-review-articles](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature-review-articles)

Comment: I've revised my original question to remove the abbreviation.